# What exactly does "removing an app" from the multitasking list do?

Tags: android

[image]

When I remove the app from the multitask list, it doesn't seem to kill the app's processes + services, but when I reopen the app, it starts from the "beginning" such as the homepage. What exactly does removing the app from the multitask list do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally removing an app from your multitask list is the same as quitting an active app (by hitting the back button continuously). The app stops functioning and the background processes linked to the app are killed. But, as you mentioned, it doesn't always happen because there are certain apps that require certain processes to run- for instance, closing an email app still lets it check for email and perform certain functions.
Force stopping your app is what actually kills all background processes as well, however again there are certain apps that still avoid this- this could be because they have some sort of link to the maker of the OS that allows those processes to run. For example, the Gmail app and Android OS both belong to Google, so they probably can decide how their app runs regardless of what you do as an end user.